# Angular Modal undefined nativeElement

Tags: html, angular

I'm getting the following error when trying to close my modal:

> cannot read property `nativeElement` of undefined

The element has been rendered by time i'm trying to close it so I'm not sure what else it could be.

**Modal code:**

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="close()">Close</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @ViewChild('myModal') closeModal: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  close() {
    this.closeModal.nativeElement.click();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) uses a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-), not the `id`, to refer to the element. You should set the variable `myModal` on the target element in the template markup:

```
<div class="modal" #myModal ...>
```

so that you can refer to that element with `ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild('myModal') closeModal: ElementRef;
```